# Cant read all data with security rules

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to read all events node as user that have admin node,
and able to read only related event if not admin.
The issue that I cant get all events with this security rule.

```
  "Event":{
      "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == 'admin'",
            ".write": true
        }
```

where my requests looks like:

```
   var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref("Event/"); //trying to read all events as admin
    starCountRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
```

Comment: Can you explain more what the issue is? Do you have eny error messages?

Comment: I don't see any errors just its just dont get in this line const data = snapshot.val(); when I remove rules its working

Comment: Does it work when you set `.read: true` ?

Comment: that is working but I need to do also for non admin "Event":{
 
            ".read":true ,
            ".write": true
        }

Comment: If that is working: are you sure that the user you test with has the value `admin` as expected?

Comment: the issue when I add "${uid}" inside the security rule event if this read:true its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem we have here is that the RTDB rules work from top down. That means if one rule in the top denies the access it doesn't matter what the one down says. In your case giving access to the whole list to the admin would be no problem but then also to each owner of the event would be. Because those are probably no admins. And you can access the whole list only when you put the `.read` above the uid.

There is one way I could imagine to make it work. There are `query-based` rules. More about them [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions).

You could write your rules like this:

```js
 "Event":{
      ".read": "query.equalTo == auth.uid || 
           root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == 'admin'" 
        }
```

You would then need to access the data with a query to get it:

```js
db.ref("Event").orderByKey()
                 .equalTo(auth.currentUser.uid)
                 .on("value", cb)
```

Comment: can you please explain why when I am trying my way I don't see any rules that its rejected from console of web? I tried also your way but got an empty object

Comment: The reason is that you need a `.read` rule above the `$uid` to view all elements in a list. That is exactly the bahaviour you see. But then when you want to give access to a single user that `.read` needs to be under the `$uid`.  Your admin rules would work but. If you put the admin rule above and single call rule under the `uid` the single call would always fail because the admin rule above would return false.